# samba is up and accesible but not showing

Tags: linux, samba, file-sharing

I have a very strange problem,

I have samba set up and running. I can access it if I use manual access like :

```
smb://myserver
```

however it does not show it on the list under my WORKGROUP. (no Folder is showing under my network)

here is the smb.conf

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP #(Set this to your Windows workgroup)
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   wins support = yes
   usershare allow guests = yes

[data]
  comment = Data share
  path = /media/external
  browseable = yes
  read only = no
  writeable = yes
  available = yes
  only guest = no
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  public = yes
```

EDIT:

**results of nmblookup:**

```
$nmblookup myserve
querying myserver on 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.3 myserver<00>
```

**results of testparm:**

```
$testparm -v
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf                                                                                                                               
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Processing section "[data]"                                                                                                                                                  
Loaded services file OK.                                                                                                                                                     
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE                                                                                                                                                 
Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
```

Comment: Output of `nmblookup` on IP of server?

Comment: @ssnobody hey mate, I've edited my question and added nmblookup

Comment: See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1891378&page=2 - check your DHCP (if you use it) and your subnet especially. Make sure your Samba server (the host OS) has the same subnet configured.

Comment: I would expect to see the WORKGROUP group in your nmblookup output. From the docs, comments lines are those which BEGIN with a `#` or `;`. Perhaps try removing the trailing comment from your workgroup specification.

Comment: @ssnobody well I'll be damned. mate I removed # from the workgroup and it worked. I have spent over 1 day on this and it was f ing me up.

Comment: @ssnobody if you answer the question i'll accept it mate (copy paste ur comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html): "Any line beginning with a semicolon (“;”) or a hash (“#”) character is ignored, as are lines containing only whitespace."

So unfortunately comments using (`#`) or (`;`) are not allowed unless the (`#`) or (`;`) occurs at the beginning of the line.

If you remove the trailing `#(Set this to your Windows workgroup)` from your workgroup directive it should work for you.